# YouTrack 2018.4 фильтр виджета

Tags: youtrack

Указываю в поисковом запросе виджета:

```
( Исполнитель: я ) и ( Состояние: -Архив )
```

В итоге выводятся записи с состоянием "Архив". Непонятно как эти фильтры виджетов работают, на офф.сайте на английском, но у меня только на русском можно вводить.

Надо чтобы виджет отображал все назначенные на меня задачи, кроме тех, что в статусе "Архив".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказалось не все поля на русский переведены, поэтому в фильтре надо было указывать так же "криво":

```
Исполнитель: я Stage: -Архив
```